# Split docx file at all Headings and keep styles?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

i try to split a docx-document using at all "Heading 1" using the following code:

```
from docx import Document
import sys
import os

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 
fn = os.path.join(path, "inp.docx")
document = Document(fn)

newDoc = False
counter = 1
for p in document.paragraphs:
  wStyleName = p.style.name
  wText = p.text
  if wStyleName == "Heading 1":
    if newDoc:
      fnOut = os.path.join(path, f"out{counter}.docx")
      newDoc.save(fnOut)
      print(f"Saving {fnOut}")
      counter += 1
      if counter > 5:
        break
    newDoc = Document()
  
  if "Heading 1" in wStyleName:
    newDoc.add_heading(wText, level=1)
  elif "Heading 2" in wStyleName:
    newDoc.add_heading(wText, level=2)
  else:
    newP = newDoc.add_paragraph()
    newP.paragraph_format.alignment = p.paragraph_format.alignment
    for row in p.runs:
        output_row = newP.add_run(row.text)
        output_row.style.name = row.style.name
        output_row.font.size = row.font.size
        output_row.bold = row.bold
        output_row.italic = row.italic
        output_row.underline = row.underline
        output_row.font.color.rgb = row.font.color.rgb
```

Generally this works fine but i am not able to keep especially the list numbering in the splitted files as you can see attached - and also the formating is different.

Input-File:
[image]

Output-File:
[image]